# Convert string to array - jQuery.inArray() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a string that looks like this (this is a value I get from an input in the page's HTML):

```
'[123,234,345]'
```

I turn this value into an array in my JS:

```
var tempProjectTasks = $('#task_id_array').val();
tempProjectTasks = tempProjectTasks.replace('[', '').replace(']','');
selectedProjectTasks = tempProjectTasks.split(',');
```

I then compare this array in a loop

```
$.each(tasks, function(key, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value['id'], selectedProjectTasks) != -1) {
        checked = 'checked';
    } else {
        checked = '';
    }
    ... more stuff here ...
});
```

This is building a list for the HTML and each row contains a checkbox.

I can see in the console the comparison for these values being `-1` by adding the `console.log` commands below inside the loop.

```
console.log(selectedProjectTasks);
console.log(value['id']);
console.log($.inArray(value['id'], selectedProjectTasks));
```

In the console:

```
["123","234","345"]
123
-1
```

Why is the `inArray()` not finding the matching values? What have I missed? Thanks

Comment: What is `value['id']`? Is it a badly formed array or an object?

Comment: maybe you should try using parseInt() on value['id']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`["123","234","345"]` is an array of string, where as  `123` is an integer.

You can convert this to string using [**toString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) before searching it in array

```
console.log($.inArray((value['id'].toString(), selectedProjectTasks));
```

Comment: i like your solution better than my finding. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer lies in the $.inArray() [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), where it says

> The comparison between values is strict. The following will return -1 (not found) because a number is being searched in an array of strings

You should either convert your new array to numbers or your compared value to a string. Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I was comparing string elements to integers so `inArray()` was failing.

I just added the following line and voila!

```
var tempProjectTasks = $('#task_id_array').val();
tempProjectTasks = tempProjectTasks.replace('[', '').replace(']','');
selectedProjectTasks = tempProjectTasks.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < selectedProjectTasks.length; i++) selectedProjectTasks[i] = +selectedProjectTasks[i];
```

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks.

Comment: You should explain why/how what you are doing works and why it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this one

```
var arrStr = str.replace(']','').replace('[','').split(",")
arrStr = arrStr.map(Number);
$.inArray(123,arrStr);
```

You can do it without `jQuery` function using [JavaSscript#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var arrStr = str.replace(']','').replace('[','').split(",")
arrStr = arrStr.map(Number);
arrStr.indexOf(value['id']);
 // return -1 id no find otherwise return index of the element.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the comparision that `inArray()` does is `strict`. You can use `$.grep()` instead.

RegularExpression specific approach.

```js
var strArray = '[123,234,345]';
var selectedProjectTasks = (/^\[(.*)\]$/g.exec(strArray)[1]).split(",")

console.log(selectedProjectTasks[0], selectedProjectTasks[1], selectedProjectTasks[2]);

//then you can do your comparisions
var value = [], checked;
value['id'] = 123;

if (($.grep(selectedProjectTasks, function(n) { return n == value['id']; })) != '[]') {
    checked = 'checked';
} else {
    checked = '';
}

console.log(checked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```